# How to run virtual machines on top of Windows 7?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, virtual-machine, windows-2000

I have a couple of Windows 2000 Virtual machines.  The virtual machine built into Windows 7 runs WinXP VMs fine, but anything previous to that...the experience is pretty crappy (for one, integration components won't install).

How does one run VMs on Win7 x64?  I looked up Virtual PC 2007 and it says Win7 is not supported (Vista is though).

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While VirtualBox is highly recommended, you can still get Virtual PC for windows 7: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx

Answer (score 4):

[VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) is an excellent tool.  Open source and support most OS. There is an open source version as well as a free/paid version (with some closed source features).  The license is very generous even for commercial use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use third-party software to run a larger number of virtual machine variants. Take a look at something like [VMWare Workstation](http://www.vmware.com/products/workstation/overview.html) -- it runs on Windows 7 and can run all kind of OS variants in its hypervisor.

VMWare makes a tool called [VMWare vCenter Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) than can convert Microsoft Hyper-V VMs to the VMWare format. [It's free to use the standalone converter](http://www.vmware.com/go/getconverter) if you don't want support.

Answer (score 1):

As well with VMWare, as said before, I highly recommend [Virtualbox](http://www.virtualbox.org/). It is open source, has a good community, and good additions in order to control your VM better. It works with any system.

> Presently, VirtualBox runs on Windows,
>   Linux, Macintosh, and Solaris hosts
>   and supports a large number of guest
>   operating systems including but not
>   limited to Windows (NT 4.0, 2000, XP,
>   Server 2003, Vista, Windows 7),
>   DOS/Windows 3.x, Linux (2.4 and 2.6),
>   Solaris and OpenSolaris, OS/2, and
>   OpenBSD.

**EDIT by enedene**:
Virtualbox is great, it's free, but only OSE version is open source. OSE lacks USB support. I use it all the time and can confirm it's great, however I'm not sure about windows2000 support, that needs to be checked, winXP works fine.